# merge two projects in one using library

Tags: android

I have two android project, for example i want to make my first project as a library and make a button in the second ^project that help me to access to the first project library. my question is how to code the access to the library ?

Comment: what IDE are you using? Android Studio or Eclipse?

Comment: i'm using Eclipse bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say as a Library but i think you mean launch another Activity.

```
launch(getApplicationContext(), "com.example.myactivity");
```

And this is the method to launch another Activity

```
public static void launch(Context context, String packageName) {
        Intent intent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);

        if (intent == null) {
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(packageName));
        }
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you replace with your package name and this method is quite broad, it finds any activity designated as a main activity. Which is fine unless you have multiple activities listed like so

```
      <activity
                android:name=".activity.WelcomeActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
 <activity 
android:name=".activity.MainActivity"> 
 <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
            </activity>
```

in this case it will find both activities, but for your needs i think just the package name will do

for this in the manifest you do not need to make any changes. can pick any app from the market and find its package and if it is installed it will launch it

Comment: Thank you Bro now i understand